# Adding multiple custom LinearLayouts to LinearLayout, only first shows up

Tags: android, custom-component

So I'm still trying to add a LinearLayout every time I click a button.

Now the way I found lets show up only the first one I add, all others don't seem to be added or not on the visible surface of the Activity.

First of all, my class CustomLinearLayout

```
public class CustomLinearLayout extends LinearLayout{

    public View v1, v2, v3, v4;
    public CheckBox cb;
    public TextView tv1, tv2;
    public EditText et1, et2;

    public CustomLinearLayout(int set, Context context){
        super(context);
        setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        cb = new CheckBox(context);
        cb.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 2));

        tv1 = new TextView(context);
        tv1.setText(" Set " + set);
        tv1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 2));

        v1 = new View(context);
        v1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));

        et1 = new EditText(context);
        et1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 2));

        v2 = new View(context);
        v2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));

        tv2 = new TextView(context);
        tv2.setText(":");

        v3 = new View(context);
        v3.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));

        et2 = new EditText(context);
        et1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 2));

        v4 = new View(context);
        v4.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));

        addView(cb);
        addView(tv1);
        addView(v2);
        addView(et1);
        addView(v3);
        addView(tv2);
        addView(v1);
        addView(et2);
        addView(v4);
    }
}
```

My layout xml-file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lin_ppe2_main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp" 
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView style="@style/TextHeader"
        android:id="@+id/tv_ppe2_header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title_pingpong_entry"
        />

      <Button 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+"
        android:onClick="onClickAddNewSet"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

and Activity itself

```
public class ChallengeActivity extends Activity {

    Vector<CustomLinearLayout> layouts = new Vector<CustomLinearLayout>();
    int counter = 0;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_pingpong_entry2);

        for(int i=1; i<8; i++){
            layouts.add(new CustomLinearLayout(i, this));
        }
    }

    public void onClickAddNewSet(View v){
        LinearLayout lin = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lin_ppe2_main);
        lin.addView(layouts.elementAt(counter));
        counter++;
    }
}
```

And following is what I get after clicking more than once, no matte how often (the layout itself it's not designed very well yet, but that is secondary):

[image]

I thought that due it's a LinearLayout with orientation=vertical, it should automatically add every new View below the last one. Why is this not done? Why does the first Layout works fine, but after the second nothing is shown up? I tried also to set orientation:vertical to the CustomLinearLayout, but then nothing showed up.

**UPDATE:**  As recommended, I tried to use the hierarchyviewer. As I tried to add a second view, i had following error message:

```
09-26 18:40:54.489: E/AndroidRuntime(7341): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-26 18:40:54.489: E/AndroidRuntime(7341): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
09-26 18:40:54.489: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
09-26 18:40:54.489: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
09-26 18:40:54.489: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
09-26 18:40:54.489: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-26 18:40:54.489: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-26 18:40:54.489: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-26 18:40:54.489: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-26 18:40:54.489: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-26 18:40:54.489: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-26 18:40:54.489: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-26 18:40:54.489: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-26 18:40:54.489: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-26 18:40:54.489: E/AndroidRuntime(7341): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
09-26 18:40:54.489: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-26 18:40:54.489: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-26 18:40:54.489: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
09-26 18:40:54.489: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     ... 11 more
09-26 18:40:54.489: E/AndroidRuntime(7341): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
09-26 18:40:54.489: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:1976)
09-26 18:40:54.489: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1871)
09-26 18:40:54.489: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1828)
09-26 18:40:54.489: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1808)
09-26 18:40:54.489: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at challenge.main.ChallengeActivity.onClickAddNewSet(ChallengeActivity.java:49)
09-26 18:40:54.489: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     ... 14 more
```

after adding one Custom Layout, hierarchyviewer says following (red marked is the custom view), after the second time the app crushes.

[image]

Comment: Did you use the hierarchy viewer to see where are those extra layouts added?

Comment: No, I never heard about that, how can I use it?

Comment: Go to the folder where you installed the android sdk -> go to `tools` -> `hierarchyviewer.bat` . Start the emulator, run your app, add some views and then in the hierarchy viewer's window select your activity -> `Load view hierarchy`.

Comment: Can you press in `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.`and tell us the line ?

Comment: I'd highly recommend looking into using a `ListView` with a custom `ListAdapter` instead of creating a ton of LinearLayouts by hand. You'll save yourself memory and eventually headache when you decide you want more than fit on a screen.

Comment: @TiagoAlmeida the line is 'lin.addView(layouts.elementAt(counter));', I don't really understand what you mean with "press in" :-)

Comment: In the logcat you can click in the line's error and it send you to the line that caused that mess :p

Comment: @TiagoAlmeida ok, now I got it. It's the line I mentioned above, lin.addView(layouts.elementAt(counter));

Comment: @StevePomeroy I made a ListView with CustomAdapter like here http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429. But how can I access let's say EditText's that I put in a custom_list_item?

Comment: @ValentinoRu assign the container of each list (the `LinearLayout` or whatever) item a tag using `setTag()` and then call `listView.findByTag()` to get them.